# SQL need to return data even if specific where statement isnt matched

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

I've built an extension to a employment application where we can easily add new questions to the form. I need to query to match on both which job they applied to and what application ID it is. I need to return both the answer and the question, the problem is it will return both if both are defined, but I need it to return the question, even if the application isn't defined, but right now it'll only return the question if the answer is defined.

Please help!

Code: (Note the where uses a Coldfusion variable, so nothing out of the normal)

```
    SELECT     
        dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.questionID 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.questionDefinitionID 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.AppID 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.questionText 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.questionDate1 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.questionDate2 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.questionBit 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.definitionID 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.jobTitleID 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.title AS QuestionTitle 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.questionTypeID 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.description 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.isActive 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppJobTitles.title AS JobTitle 
        ,dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionTypes.type AS QuestionType    
    FROM dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers 
        FULL JOIN dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions 
            ON dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.questionDefinitionID = dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.definitionID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.mod_employmentAppJobTitles 
            ON dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.jobTitleID = dbo.mod_employmentAppJobTitles.jobTitleID 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionTypes 
            ON dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.questionTypeID = dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionTypes.questionTypeID
    WHERE   
        (dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions.jobTitleID = 
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#jobTitleID#" />) AND
        (dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers.AppID = 
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#applicationID#" />)
```

Database design below: 
[image: Database design]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use left across. I'm not sure you used `FULL JOIN` intentionally except in an attempt to get better results, right? Also please learn to use aliases for tables in your joins - people who have to read your code will thank you, I promise.

```
SELECT     
    a.questionID 
    ,a.questionDefinitionID 
    ,a.AppID 
    ,a.questionText 
    ,a.questionDate1 
    ,a.questionDate2 
    ,a.questionBit 
    ,d.definitionID 
    ,d.jobTitleID 
    ,d.title AS QuestionTitle 
    ,d.questionTypeID 
    ,d.description 
    ,d.isActive 
    ,t.title AS JobTitle 
    ,qt.type AS QuestionType    
FROM
    dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionDefinitions AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionAnswers AS a 
    ON a.questionDefinitionID = d.definitionID 
    AND a.AppID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#applicationID#" />
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.mod_employmentAppJobTitles AS t
    ON d.jobTitleID = t.jobTitleID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.mod_employmentAppQuestionTypes AS qt
    ON d.questionTypeID = qt.questionTypeID
WHERE   
    d.jobTitleID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#jobTitleID#" />
```

Comment: It's a style requirement of where I work not to use aliases, unless there are duplicates, but thank you so much for the help. Works great!

Comment: That's interesting. Can you share the reason behind no using table aliases? Folks there like to type A LOT?

Answer (score -1):

Simply you have to use left outer join there...